# std::format behaving different. between signed char / unsigned char

Tags: c++, c++20

Is this behavior expected or as per standards (used VC compiler)?

**Example 1 (signed char):**

```
char s = 'R'
std::cout << s << std::endl;         // Prints R.
std::cout << std::format("{}\n", s); // Prints R.
```

**Example 2 (unsigned char):**

```
unsigned char u = 'R';
std::cout << u << std::endl;         // Prints R.
std::cout << std::format("{}\n", u); // Prints 82.
```

In the second example with `std::format`, `u` is printed as `82` instead of `R`, is it a bug or expected behavior?

Without using `std::format`, if just by `std::cout`, I get `R` in both examples.

Comment: Aside: Whether plain char is a signed or unsigned type is implementation defined. Also it is a distinct type from both the signed char and unsigned char types.

Comment: Please don't spam C++ versions in the tags. `std::format` is not available in the older C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is intentional and specified as such in the standard.

Both `char` and `unsigned char` are fundamentally numeric types. Normally only `char` has the additional meaning of representing a character. For example there are no `unsigned char` string literals. If `unsigned char` is used, often aliased to `std::uint8_t`, then it is normally supposed to represent a numeric value (or a raw byte of memory, although `std::byte` is a better choice for that).

So it makes sense to choose a numeric interpretation for `unsigned char` and a character interpretation for `char` by default. In both cases that can be overwritten with `{:c}` as specifier for a character interpretation and `{:d}` for a numeric interpretation.

I think `operator<<`'s behavior is the non-intuitive one, but that has been around for much longer and probably can't be changed.

---

Also note that `signed char` is a completely distinct type from both `char` and `unsigned char` and that it is implementation-defined whether `char` is an signed or unsigned integer type (but always distinct from both `signed` and `unsigned` char).

If you used `signed char` it would also be interpreted as numeric by default for the same reason as `unsigned char` is.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the section that details this in the standard: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/format#arg-5

Comment: @NathanOliver No, it is https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/format#string.std-19 (applying to all integral types except `charT`, which here is `char`, and `bool`) and https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/format#string.std-20 applying to `charT`. In each case see the `none` entry in the table.

Answer (score 1):

> In the second example `std::format`, its printed as 82 instead of `'R'`,
> Is it an issue or standard?

This is behavior defined by the standard, according to [[format.string.std]](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:format.type.int):

| Type | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| `c` | Copies the character `static_­cast<charT>(value)` to the output. Throws `format_­error` if `value` is not in the range of representable values for `charT`. |
| `d` | `to_­chars(first, last, value)`. |
| ... | ... |
| none | The same as `d`. [*Note 8*: If the formatting argument type is `charT` or `bool`, the default is instead `c` or `s`, respectively. — *end note*] |

For integer types, if *type* options are not specified, then `d` will be the default. Since `unsigned char` is an integer type, it will be interpreted as an integer, and its value will be the value converted by `std::to_chars`.

(Except for `charT` type and `bool` type, the default *type* options are `c` or `s`)